# HKSampleQuery for workout route returns no samples even though one exists

Tags: ios, core-location, apple-watch, healthkit

## Overview

I have 2 cycling workouts (recorded using the Workouts app on an Apple Watch SE) that I'm trying to retrieve the location data (GPX samples) from. They were part of the same continuous ride that I recorded using 2 separate workouts due to the original workout being unable to unpause midway through. Ultimately, I'd like to obtain all location samples and merge them into a single file.

## Current State

The health app on my iPhone (SE, 2020) correctly shows 2 workouts on the day I recorded them (July 16th), and also contains 4 workout route objects for the 2 workouts: 1 that makes up the entirety of the first workout, and 3 that combine to make up the second workout.

[Screenshot showing 2 workouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q82s.png)

[Screenshot showing 4 workout routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sev8S.png)

When I export the raw health data however, only 3 workout routes show up for July 16th. And they're all for the second workout. No GPX route file is exported for the first workout.

## Attempt to Solve

In an attempt to try and access the raw data from HealthKit directly, I found an [app on Github](https://github.com/pilif/GpxExport), built it, and loaded it onto my iPhone to see what I could get. The app retrieves a list of workouts, and exports a GPX file with all location samples when a workout is selected. This works great with the second of my cycling workouts, but crashes when trying to export the data from the first workout.

Here's the function that actually queries the workout for route information:

```
public func route(for workout: HKWorkout, completion: @escaping (([CLLocation]?, Error?) -> Swift.Void)) {
    let routeType = HKSeriesType.workoutRoute();
    let p = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: workout)
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierStartDate, ascending: true)
    
    let q = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: routeType, predicate: p, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) {
        (query, samples, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
            return
        }
        
        guard let routeSamples: [HKWorkoutRoute] = samples as? [HKWorkoutRoute] else { print("No route samples"); return }

        if (routeSamples.count == 0){
            completion([CLLocation](), nil)
            return;
        }
        var sampleCounter = 0
        var routeLocations:[CLLocation] = []

        for routeSample: HKWorkoutRoute in routeSamples {
            
            let locationQuery: HKWorkoutRouteQuery = HKWorkoutRouteQuery(route: routeSample) { _, locationResults, done, error in
                guard locationResults != nil else {
                    print("Error occured while querying for locations: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(nil, error)
                    }
                    return
                }

                if done {
                    sampleCounter += 1
                    if sampleCounter != routeSamples.count {
                        if let locations = locationResults {
                            routeLocations.append(contentsOf: locations)
                        }
                    } else {
                        if let locations = locationResults {
                            routeLocations.append(contentsOf: locations)
                            let sortedLocations = routeLocations.sorted(by: {$0.timestamp < $1.timestamp})
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                completion(sortedLocations, error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if let locations = locationResults {
                        routeLocations.append(contentsOf: locations)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            self.healthStore.execute(locationQuery)
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(q)
}
```

After further debugging, it appears that the `HKSampleQuery` call is returning 0 samples when querying the first cycling workout. It returns 3 samples (each of the workout route objects) when querying the second cycling workout.

So it's as if the HealthKit API can't see the 4th workout route, even though it clearly exists as evidenced by the screenshot from the health app.

## Question

What's going on here? Why does the second workout return data just fine but the first doesn't?

Is it possible to query the health database directly to obtain this data? I have a local encrypted iPhone backup with a known passcode I can access as well.

This cycling ride was pretty important to me, so I'm trying all I can to retrieve the location data. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: Adding main code where the `route()` function gets called.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath);
        guard let workouts = self.workouts else {
            return;
        }


        if (indexPath.row >= workouts.count){
            return;
        }

        print(indexPath.row)
        let workout = workouts[indexPath.row];
        let workout_name: String = {
            switch workout.workoutActivityType {
                case .cycling: return "Cycle"
                case .running: return "Run"
                case .walking: return "Walk"
                default: return "Workout"
            }
        }()
        let workout_title = "\(workout_name) - \(self.dateFormatter.string(from: workout.startDate))"
        let file_name = "\(self.filenameDateFormatter.string(from: workout.startDate)) - \(workout_name)"

        let targetURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(file_name)
            .appendingPathExtension("gpx")

        let file: FileHandle

        do {
            let manager = FileManager.default;
            if manager.fileExists(atPath: targetURL.path){
                try manager.removeItem(atPath: targetURL.path)
            }
            print(manager.createFile(atPath: targetURL.path, contents: Data()))
            file = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: targetURL);
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
            return
        }

        workoutStore.heartRate(for: workouts[indexPath.row]){
            (rates, error) in

            guard let keyedRates = rates, error == nil else {
                print(error as Any);
                return
            }

            let iso_formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
            var current_heart_rate_index = 0;
            var current_hr: Double = -1;
            let bpm_unit = HKUnit(from: "count/min")
            var hr_string = "";
            file.write(
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><gpx version=\"1.1\" creator=\"Apple Workouts (via pilif's hack of the week)\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd\" xmlns:gpxtpx=\"http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1\"><trk><name><![CDATA[\(workout_title)]]></name><time>\(iso_formatter.string(from: workout.startDate))</time><trkseg>"
                        .data(using: .utf8)!
            )

            self.workoutStore.route(for: workouts[indexPath.row]){
                (maybe_locations, error) in
                guard let locations = maybe_locations, error == nil else {
                    print(error as Any);
                    file.closeFile()
                    return
                }

                for location in locations {
                    while (current_heart_rate_index < keyedRates.count) && (location.timestamp > keyedRates[current_heart_rate_index].startDate) {
                        current_hr = keyedRates[current_heart_rate_index].quantity.doubleValue(for: bpm_unit)
                        current_heart_rate_index += 1;
                        hr_string = "<extensions><gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension><gpxtpx:hr>\(current_hr)</gpxtpx:hr></gpxtpx:TrackPointExtension></extensions>"
                    }

                    file.write(
                        "<trkpt lat=\"\(location.coordinate.latitude)\" lon=\"\(location.coordinate.longitude)\"><ele>\(location.altitude.magnitude)</ele><time>\(iso_formatter.string(from: location.timestamp))</time>\(hr_string)</trkpt>"
                            .data(using: .utf8)!
                    )
                }
                file.write("</trkseg></trk></gpx>".data(using: .utf8)!)
                file.closeFile()

                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController( activityItems: [targetURL],
                                                                       applicationActivities: nil)
                if let popoverPresentationController = activityViewController.popoverPresentationController {
                    popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = nil
                }
                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the code where you call this function.

Comment: See edit, added code that calls `route()` function

Answer (score 0):

You say Health shows the data, what about Fitness? If you can see the route in Fitness it exists and you should be able to extract it.

Assuming you are getting the "No route samples" from your guard statement in route(), you should verify the workout you are passing. Also, you could change the predicate p to specify the workout.start and workout.end times.

You could also insert a temporary debug print statement above the guard to see what's being returned:

print("samples: (String(describing: samples))").